# How to remove the "lighter color" effect when disabling an options menu item?

Tags: android, menu

how can I remove the "lighter color" effect when disabling an options menu item? I'd like

```
menu.getItem(cur_menu_item).setEnabled(false);
```

to only disable the click, without changing the color of my item.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just do nothing in your `onOptionsItemSelected()` function for this particular menu id when you consider it disabled. That is, without disabling the menu item itself.

Comment: Perhaps you can try this approach for your particular menu ids:

http://www.techjini.com/blog/2011/04/19/customizing-background-and-text-color-in-options-menu-android/